# Attribute Error: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am attempting to do a text generation program using Keras and Tensorflow. I have come across the problem while trying to use the predict_classes. After a quick research, I learnt that the predict_classes has been removed in the new Tensorflow version, but I have not received any satisfactory solution. My code is given below:

```
def generate_text_seq(model, tokenizer, text_seq_length, seed_text, n_words):
  text = []
  for _ in range(n_words):
    encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([seed_text])[0]
    encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen = text_seq_length, truncating = 'pre')
    y_pred = model.predict_classes(encoded)
    predicted_word = ''
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
      if index == y_pred.any():
        predicted_word = word
        break
      seed_text = seed_text + ' ' + predicted_word
      text.append(predicted_word)
    return ' '.join(text)
```

The code is a text generating function, that generates the next token given a seed text. I have used this code from multiple online lectures, but most of those videos were outdated, so they still used the predict_classes method.

Here is the error I was receiving: [Error in Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqDP1.png)

I have tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked. For one, I used the .predict() method directly but I was not getting the correct answer.

I also tried the following code as well:

```
def generate_text_seq(model, tokenizer, text_seq_length, seed_text, n_words):
  text = []
  for _ in range(n_words):
    encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([seed_text])[0]
    encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen = text_seq_length, truncating = 'pre')
    pred_y = model.predict(encoded)
    y_pred = np.argmax(pred_y, axis = 1)
    predicted_word = ''
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
      if index == y_pred:
        predicted_word = word
        break
      seed_text = seed_text + ' ' + predicted_word
      text.append(predicted_word)
    return ' '.join(text)
```

Comment: You need to use `predict()` despite using predict_class() and then use np.argmax() to find the max probabaility of the class to get the exact predicted class.